# List the lengths of all the prefix-suffixes in $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ time

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, strings

A proper prefix of a string $s$ that is also equal to a suffix of $s$ is called a PS (prefix-suffix).

Given a string $s$ of length $n$ is there an algorithm listing the lengths of all the PSs in $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ time?

KMP can find the *longest* PS in linear time. Then we can note that the second longest PS is the longest PS of the longest PS so we can apply KMP iteratively but that is $O(n^2)$ in the worst case (e.g. if $s=aaaa\dots a$).

Answer (score 1):

Simply note that KMP is incremental: it finds the longest PS (also known as *border*) for every prefix of the string. If you don't throw away that information, you don't need to re-run KMP for every prefix.